# varchar date conversion to max() date() mysql

Tags: mysql, date-conversion

In my database the column type is varchar(30) which stores date (24/02/2018), having multiple records.
i want the maximum date e.g i have 10/01/2016, 20/03/2017, 24/02/2018.
I am using the below query:

```
SELECT MAX(receipt_date) as rd FROM tblname
```

which returns me 10/01/2016 which is wrong.
i also tried to convert it to date format. but failed. mysql gives me syntax error.

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, mycolumn, 105) FROM tblname
```

but failed.

Comment: Step 1. Store dates as dates. Then get back to usz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I'd do:

```
ALTER TABLE tblname ADD COLUMN receipt_date2 DATE;

UPDATE tblname SET receipt_date2 = STR_TO_DATE(receipt_date, '%d/%m/%Y');

ALTER TABLE tblname DROP COLUMN receipt_date,
  CHANGE receipt_date2 receipt_date DATE;

SELECT MAX(receipt_date) AS rd FROM tblname;
```

You can't use dates effectively in MySQL if you store than as VARCHAR in dd-mm-yyyy format. You should use a `DATE` data type. MySQL's `DATE` data type stores dates in yyyy-mm-dd format only. This way it can search for `MAX()` easily, it can sort them, it can do date arithmetic.

Comment: I'm glad I could help!